# python importエラー

Tags: python, python3

Flaskでログイン時のパスワードを管理するためwerkzeugを使うため、以下の様に記載していますが、importエラーが発生してしまいます。
色々調べていますが、何が間違っているか分からない状況です。
ご教示の程、よろしくお願い致します。

```
from werkzeug.security import generete_password_hash, check_password_hash
```

エラー内容

```
from werkzeug.security import generete_password_hash, check_password_hash
ImportError: cannot import name 'generete_password_hash' from 'werkzeug.security'
```

```
Package            Version
------------------ -------
click              8.1.3
colorama           0.4.6
Flask              2.2.2
Flask-Login        0.6.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy   3.0.2
greenlet           2.0.1
importlib-metadata 5.1.0
itsdangerous       2.1.2
Jinja2             3.1.2
MarkupSafe         2.1.1
pip                21.1.3
pytz               2022.6
setuptools         56.0.0
SQLAlchemy         1.4.45
Werkzeug           2.2.2
zipp               3.11.0
```

Comment: 自己解決しました。genereteのスペルが間違っていました。

Answer (score 0):

`generete_password_hash`ではなく`generate_password_hash`でしょう。
`e`と`a`のタイプミスですね。

[werkzeug.generate_password_hash](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/werkzeug.generate_password_hash.html)